# Slider in continous circular loop

Tags: jquery, css

I have a slider, with auto rotation script, currently its sliding forth and back, I want it to rotate in circular motion, Any ideas...

Fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/y41y9866/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider">
<ul>
<li data-rel="1"><a href="#" title="Japani M Capsules"><img src="http://www.djensenphotography.com/images/anthony-_lake_shooting-.jpg" alt="Japani M Capsules" /></a></li>

<li data-rel="2"><a href="#" title="Japani M Capsules"><img src="http://www.djensenphotography.com/images/anthony-_lake_shooting-.jpg" alt="Japani M Capsules" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
*{margin:0;padding:0}
.slider { float:left; width:500px; overflow:hidden; position:relative;}
.slider li { float:left; width:500px;list-style:none;}
.slider li img { max-width:100%; display:block;}
</style>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//slider code
var slider_w = $('.slider').width();
var total_li = $('.slider li').length
var total_w = $('.slider').width()*total_li
$('.slider ul').width(total_w)

// Auto Rotaion Code
var counter = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    if (counter++ % 2) {
     $('.slider ul').animate({marginLeft:'-' + slider_w},500)
    } else {
     $('.slider ul').animate({marginLeft:'0'},500)
    }
}, 3000);

});
</script>
```

Comment: you should edit your question and add some codes

Comment: @Digitlimit: The plural of code is code :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie thanks I didn't know :(. Correction taken tnks!

Comment: @Digitlimit: No problem. It is short for `source code` (which covers both the singular or plural). There is not such thing as `source codes` :)

Comment: @Dipesh Rana: Best way to *not* get help on SO is to start complaining... Best delete your comment ASAP :)

Comment: Q: When you say `circular`, do you actually mean endlessly in one direction, or in a circle? :)

Comment: @Dipesh Rana not everyone likes fiddle

Comment: Very true @TrueBlueAussie, especially when you are complaining about the rules that are there to help us help you!

Comment: Okay, you need to simply place the next item to be shown beside the visible one then animate both. That usually means tracking which one is the "current" one (e.g. using a class or index variable). Best to allow for more than 2 images, so I would recommend using a class to mark the current one.

Comment: Really bad example added below. You can clean it up to suit (it was too big for a comment) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is that you need to remove the first child and append it in the same list like,

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(".slider ul").animate({
        'marginLeft': '-=' + slider_w + 'px'
    }, 1000, function () {
        $(".slider ul li:first-child").appendTo(".slider ul");
        $(".slider ul").css({
            'marginLeft': '+=' + slider_w + 'px'
        });
    });
}, 3000);
```

Then it will work as circular list(remember the data structure if you read)

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/y41y9866/13/)

Comment: That's nice and simple. Deleted mine :)

Comment: @Rohan, Thanks for the answer but I am using pagers also so they are creating problem, check Fiddle:-http://jsfiddle.net/3p4wh2cL/1/

Comment: I think, you are wasting time so try https://amazingslider.com or search `image sliders jquery` on http://google.com